# Multiple UIBarButtonItems using XIB

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add more than two `UIBarButtonItems` **using the XIB**. I know how to do this programatically. But shouldn't it be possible via the XIB as well? Not worrying about the ascetic of the app. Just want to know if its feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `UIBarButtons` in an the `XIB` and show them like this.

**Yes** you can , after trying ....

**EDIT :**
Please see the following method ,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Gill just read question again , he is saying "I know how to do this programatically."

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Yeah rite ... In the near future you will not be the only one reading this answer are you ??

Comment: @IronManGill - uff... copy paste.. :P

Comment: @Rajneesh071 U think so ? BTW I have used a toolbar and have shown it in the XIB as Tested too .... Coding will remain coding dude ....

Answer (score 0):

In a `UINavigation` Object you can add only two bar buttons via `nib`:
**Left Bar button** and  **Right bar button**.

You cannot add any Flexible Space Bar Button Item.

Comment: you can add a view , and that view contain button.

Comment: The OP asked :I want to add more than two UIBarButtonItems using the XIB.
As far as I know you cannot add a bar button - UIBarButton- on a UIView object. So the question looks like: How to add a bar button item on toolbar or a navigation bar?
@vishwa.deepak tells how to add bar buttons on a toolbar , and I answered what I knew of Navihgation Bar.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

Simply add buttons with flexible space in between them, more than 4 will really look bad but you can give a try.

Comment: he even didnt mentioned toolbar or navigation bar :P